# How to solve transcendental coupled equations?

Tags: equation-solving, nonlinear

Dear Mathematica users,

I am trying to solve the following system of transcendental equations,

$$
f(\eta,y,\theta) = y - \frac{2}{\eta}{\textrm{Coth}(\frac{3 y \eta}{4 \theta})}=0,
$$
$$
g(\eta,y,\theta) = \frac{3}{2}\eta^2y^2 - 1 - y^2 - \frac{y}{\eta}{\textrm{Coth}(\frac{3 y \eta}{4 \theta})}=0,
$$
for different values of $\theta$. I tried secant find root but it seems to give a solution with a warning

> " The point {0.4,0.349163} is at the edge of the search region
> {0.001,0.4} in coordinate 1 and the computed search direction points
> outside the region."

```
f[\[Eta]1_, y_, \[Theta]_] := 
 y - 2/\[Eta]1 Coth[3 y \[Eta]1/(4 \[Theta])]
g[\[Eta]1_, y_, \[Theta]_] := 
 3/2 \[Eta]1^2 y^2 - 1 - y^2  - 
  y/\[Eta]1 Coth[3 y \[Eta]1/(4 \[Theta])]

ContourPlot[{f[x, y, 0.001] == g[x, y, 0.001]}, {x, 0, 0.5}, {y, 0, 
  1}, PlotRange -> All]

FindRoot[{f[x, y, 0.001] == 0, 
  g[x, y, 0.001] == 0}, {{x, 0.01, 0.001, 0.4}, {y, 0.9, 0.00001, 1}},
  MaxIterations -> 1000]
```

I chose a guess based on the contour plot. What stupid thing am I doing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[η1_, y_, θ_] := y - 2/η1 Coth[3 y η1/(4 θ)]
g[η1_, y_, θ_] := 3/2 η1^2 y^2 - 1 - y^2 - y/η1 Coth[3 y η1/(4 θ)]

ContourPlot[{f[x, y, 10^-3] == 0, g[x, y, 10^-3] == 0},
 {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

```
FindRoot[{f[x, y, 10^-3] == 0, g[x, y, 10^-3] == 0},
   {{x, #[[1]]}, {y, #[[2]]}}] & /@
 {{-1, -2}, {-1, 2}, {1, -2}, {1, 2}}

(* {{x -> -1.09545, y -> -1.82574}, {x -> -1.09545, 
  y -> 1.82574}, {x -> 1.09545, y -> -1.82574}, {x -> 1.09545, 
  y -> 1.82574}} *)
```

Comment: Indeed I was doing something stupid in that f=0=g has a solution set different from f=g.

Answer (score 5):

We can solve it by `DiscretizeRegion`.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
f[η1_, y_, θ_] = 
  y - 2/η1 Coth[3 y η1/(4 θ)];
g[η1_, y_, θ_] = 
  3/2 η1^2 y^2 - 1 - y^2 - 
   y/η1 Coth[3 y η1/(4 θ)];
reg = ImplicitRegion[{f[x, y, 0.001] == 0, 
    g[x, y, 0.001] == 0}, {{x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}}];
dreg = DiscretizeRegion[reg];
pts = MeshPrimitives[dreg, 0][[;; , 1]]
```

[image]

```
ContourPlot[{f[x, y, 0.001] == 0, g[x, y, 0.001] == 0}, {x, -5, 
  5}, {y, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 80, 
 MaxRecursion -> 4, Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[5], Red, Point[pts]}]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for teaching me a new technique. I wish I could upvote multiple answers.

Comment: @Charlie you can upvote the answer by the upper triangle  ▲  on the left of the answer.