# FindRoot and indeterminate expression

Tags: equation-solving

I have tried the following with several different starting points and always returns errors:

```
FindRoot[{Sum[n (E^(-a/n - b n))/(Sum[E^(-a/n - b n), {n, 3, 12}]), {n, 3, 12}] - 6, 
E^(-a/6 - b 6)/(Sum[E^(-a/n - b n), {n, 3, 12}]) - 0}, {{a, -2}, {b, -1}}]
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You are getting divide by zero at one point during the search for root.

Comment: If you do `Simplify` on your list of two expressions then the result is MUCH simpler. Both those expressions are over the same denominator. The numerator of the second expression is E^(a/6+6b). You want that 2nd expression==0 so you want that 2nd numerator==0 and that is never going to happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- There no solution for the second equation.

```
Reduce[E^(-a/6 - b 6)/(Sum[E^(-a/n - b n), {n, 3, 12}]) - 0==0,{a,b},Reals]
```

> `False`.

- We need to change such equation for example, change `0` to `10^-10`.If we do not want to set the initial values, we can use`DiscretizeRegion` to find such roots.
  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/280660/72111

```
Clear[eq1, eq2, reg, dreg];
eq1 = Sum[
    n (E^(-a/n - b n))/(Sum[E^(-a/n - b n), {n, 3, 12}]), {n, 3, 
     12}] - 6;
eq2 = E^(-a/6 - b 6)/(Sum[E^(-a/n - b n), {n, 3, 12}]) - 10^-10;
reg = ImplicitRegion[{eq1 == 0, 
    eq2 == 0}, {{a, -500, 500}, {b, -5, 5}}];
dreg = DiscretizeRegion[reg];
pts = MeshPrimitives[dreg, 0][[;; , 1]]
```

> `{{-268.653, -7.38512}}`

```
eq1 = Sum[
    n (E^(-a/n - b n))/(Sum[E^(-a/n - b n), {n, 3, 12}]), {n, 3, 
     12}] - 6;
eq2 = E^(-a/6 - b 6)/(Sum[E^(-a/n - b n), {n, 3, 12}]) - 10^-10;
FindRoot[{eq1,eq2}, {{a, -260}, {b, -7}}]
FindRoot[{eq1, eq2}, {a, -95}, {b, -3}]
```

> `{a -> -268.653, b -> -7.38512}`